# How to redirect the request from specific IP address to another site with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am going to redirect some requests from specific IP addresses to another site.
For example if the request come from `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` or `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxy`, I am going to redirect to `https://example.com` and for others, I am going to show my `index.php`.

So I tried like this, but this does not work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxy
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [L,R]
   
</IfModule>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxy$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [L,R]
```

Important thing to note here is use of `[OR]` clause to allow matching any of the give IP addresses and use of anchors + escaping the dots to match IPs accurately.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you need to combine the two RewriteCond statements into a single statement using the "OR" operator. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx|xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxy)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [L,R]
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For clarity :
The RewriteCond statement checks whether the remote IP address matches either "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" or "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxy".

The regular expression pattern is enclosed in parentheses, and the "OR" operator is used to separate the two IP address values.

The "NC" flag is used to make the IP address pattern case-insensitive.

So if the condition is true, the first RewriteRule is applied to redirect to "https://example.com". and if the condition is false, the second RewriteRule is applied to show the "index.php" file.